# missing 2 required positional arguments flask python

Tags: python, flask, web, bluetooth

I'm developing a web application where I pull and use bluetooth data via the browser via the Bleak library.I do not intend to connect to the database. My only purpose is to keep the person's bluettoh data on the browser (cookies or sessions) as well. I haven't gotten to this stage yet. At the moment, I just need to view the detailed bluetooth data on the browser. But I am getting this error.
"TypeError: devices() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'device' and 'advertisement_data'"

Look at my Codes

```
from flask import Flask
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner
import asyncio
from uuid import UUID
import json
from construct import Array, Byte, Const, Int8sl, Int16ub, Struct
from construct.core import ConstError
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak.backends.device import BLEDevice
from bleak.backends.scanner import AdvertisementData
app = Flask(__name__)
ibeacon_format = Struct(
    "type_length" / Const(b"\x02\x15"),
    "uuid" / Array(16, Byte),
    "major" / Int16ub,
    "minor" / Int16ub,
    "power" / Int8sl,
)
class UUIDEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, uuid):
        if isinstance(uuid, UUID):
            # if the obj is uuid, we simply return the value of uuid
            return uuid.hex
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, uuid)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"


@app.route("/beacons")
async def devices(device: BLEDevice, advertisement_data: AdvertisementData):

    try:
            macadress = device.address
            name = advertisement_data.local_name
            apple_data = advertisement_data.manufacturer_data[0x004C]
            ibeacon = ibeacon_format.parse(apple_data)
            uuid = UUID(bytes=bytes(ibeacon.uuid))
            minor = ibeacon.minor
            major = ibeacon.major
            power = ibeacon.power
            rssi = device.rssi
            rssi = int(rssi)

            beacons = {
                "Mac Adress": macadress,
                "Local Name": name,
                "UUID": uuid,
                "Major": major,
                "Minor": minor,
                "TX Power": power,
                "RSSI": rssi
            }

            if (beacons["Local Name"] == "POI" and beacons["RSSI"] <= -40 and beacons["RSSI"] >= -80):
                return print(beacons)
                # with open("data.json","a") as file:
                #     json.dump(beacons,file,sort_keys=True,indent=4,skipkeys=True,cls=UUIDEncoder,separators=(",",":"))
            else:
                pass


    except KeyError:
        # Apple company ID (0x004c) not found
        pass
    except ConstError:
        # No iBeacon (type 0x02 and length 0x15)
        pass

async def main():
    """Scan for devices."""
    scanner = BleakScanner()
    scanner.register_detection_callback(devices)

    
    while (True):
        await scanner.start()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await scanner.stop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't you call the function devices in the line:
**scanner.register_detection_callback(devices)**

If so you have to give it the two arguments device and advertisement_data.

Comment: thank you for your reply sir but i tried your advice and it didn't work'

Comment: Even if I comment  the line you told me, I get the same error.